# Pick some values from an object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to extract an ordered subset of values from an object.

```
const obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 };
const values = extractValues(obj, ['a', 'd']);
// values worthes [1, 4]
```

I know how to implement the `extractValues` function but I was wondering if something concise already exists with JavaScript vanilla or Lodash.

Comment: `const extractValues = (obj, arr) => arr.map(k => obj[k])`

Comment: I just realize that my question was badly formulated, I know how to write `extractValues`, I need something to avoid the repetition of "myFoo" in:
const ar = [ myFoo.a, myFoo.b, myFoo.c, myFoo.d ];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can get the result by iterating over your `input array` for which you want to get `values` .

```js
const obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 };
const values = extractValues(obj, ['a', 'd']);
console.log(values);
function extractValues(obj,list){
  var result = [];
  list.forEach(function(e){
    result.push(obj[e]);
  })
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use map to achieve the output

```js
const obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 };
const values =extractValues(obj, ['a', 'd']);
function extractValues(obj,arr)
{
return arr.map(function(e){return obj[e]})
}
console.log(values)
```